# Angular 5 Service Worker Cache Api

Tags: angular5, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I am currently working on an Angular 5 PWA. I am using the default service worker implementation from angular.

I want to implement a "read later" feature, which enables the user to decide what items are cached. I could not find an API from Angular for this eventhough it should be technically possible to decide what is cached while runtime.

How could i achieve this?
Thanks in advance!